# Promise isn't running within process.exit

Tags: javascript, events, promise, bluebird

Here's an example of some synchronous code that just logs hello world.

```
function syncTest() {
  console.log("hello world");
}

syncTest();
syncTest();
process.on('exit', function() {
  syncTest();
});

//hello world
//hello world
//hello world
```

This is expected It runs `syncTest()` twice then on exit once again.

I have the same code below, but with a promise in it instead.

```
function existsAsync(path) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    fs.exists(path, resolve);
  });
}

function promiseTest(projectDir) {
  var pkg = path.join(projectDir, "package.json");
  existsAsync(pkg).then(function(exists) {
    console.log("hello world");
  }).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  });
}

var projectDir = process.cwd();
promiseTest(projectDir);
promiseTest(projectDir);
process.on('exit', function() {
  promiseTest(projectDir);
});

//hello world
//hello world
```

This code with the promise only runs twice, it doesn't run inside the `exit` event for some strange reason. Is this a quirk of promises? What could be causing this? Am I not using promises the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the [`process`'s `exit` event documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit),

> Emitted when the process is about to exit. **There is no way to prevent the exiting of the event loop at this point, and once all exit listeners have finished running the process will exit.** Therefore you **must** only perform synchronous operations in this handler. This is a good hook to perform checks on the module's state (like for unit tests). The callback takes one argument, the code the process is exiting with.
>
> Example of listening for exit:
>
> ```
> process.on('exit', function(code) {
>   // do *NOT* do this
>   setTimeout(function() {
>     console.log('This will not run');
>   }, 0);
>   console.log('About to exit with code:', code);
> });
> ```

So, don't use promises in the `exit` event handler, instead make your code synchronous.

Comment: I read this in the documentation a long time ago and thought I'd never need it. Thanks so much!